# How to iterate array of objects in SendGrid templete?

Tags: node.js, templates, sendgrid

I want to iterate the following data type to show in template.

```
products:
 [ { name: 'VEEBA SWEET CHILLI SAUCE 1KG',
   qty: 2,
   price: 145,
   packSize: '1 KG',
   itemSubTotal: 290,
   comments: null },
 { name: 'Chilled French Fries',
   qty: 1,
   price: 85,
   packSize: '1 KG',
   itemSubTotal: 85,
   comments: null } ]
```

How is it possible to achieve with sendgrid? Mandrill supports Handlebar templates which have looping support, but didn't come across documentation for similar with Sendgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionals and iterating over collections are not currently supported in SendGrid. We are planning to add them in the next version of our templating. A suggested workaround is to perform your loop prior to inserting the content into the template; [sections](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/section_tags.html) may make this easier.